# preg_replace. How to use \0 in function?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to use class method as a second variable in preg_replace, like

```
$x = preg_replace('/\[\[\[(.+)\]\]\]/',
    (new ButtonGroupWidget(['idsForLoad' => ['\0']]))->run(),
    $code);
```

Idea is generate buttons instead of [[[button id]]]. Yes, this is kinda strange) And yes, I know what smarty is)

Comment: Declare a callback function and use `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: Thanks! Fits perfectly!

Comment: Post your answer, please, for correctly close question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and pass a callback function instead of a string replacement pattern into that function. If you define the match object argument as `$m`, the whole match will reside in `$m[0]`.

```
function repl($m) {
    return (new ButtonGroupWidget(['idsForLoad' => [$m[0]]]))->run();
}
$code = "[[[btn1]]] [[[btn2]]]";
$x = preg_replace_callback('/\[\[\[(.+?)]]]/', 'repl', $code);
```

I also advise to use a lazy dot matching pattern in the regex to enforce the regex to match the shortest strings between `[[[` and `]]]`. Note that `]` does not have to be escaped here.